# How to run Spring boot with older version of hibernate

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am creating a fresh new project using spring boot 1.5, with a dependent entity module ( Created way back in 2012 ).

Entity module is using older version of hibernate ( 3.3.2 ), I can't 
modify entity module.

Entity module is using following annotation which is removed with Hibernate5 ( comes default by spring boot 1.5 )

```
CollectionOfElements
MapKey
@ForeignKey
@IndexColumn
```

I know in that we can give different version of  jars can be used in spring boot, I tried by overriding but it didn't work

Any help or guide will be highly appriciated, Thanks A Lot

```
<!-- HIBERNATE OLDER VERSION COMPATIBILITY -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-annotations -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-validator -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2.GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2.GA</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: You should read this : https://spring.io/blog/2016/04/13/overriding-dependency-versions-with-spring-boot

Answer (score 2):

You should use properties to override dependency versions, however there's no guarantee that a given version of Spring Boot will work with older versions of one of its dependencies.

[Here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.5.9.RELEASE/spring-boot-dependencies/pom.xml), you can see a list of dependency version properties for Spring Boot 1.5.9:

```
<properties>
    <!-- Dependency versions -->
    <activemq.version>5.14.5</activemq.version>
    <antlr2.version>2.7.7</antlr2.version>
    <appengine-sdk.version>1.9.59</appengine-sdk.version>
    <artemis.version>1.5.5</artemis.version>
    <aspectj.version>1.8.13</aspectj.version>
    <assertj.version>2.6.0</assertj.version>
    <atomikos.version>3.9.3</atomikos.version>
    <bitronix.version>2.1.4</bitronix.version>
    <caffeine.version>2.3.5</caffeine.version>
    <cassandra-driver.version>3.1.4</cassandra-driver.version>
    <classmate.version>1.3.4</classmate.version>
    <commons-beanutils.version>1.9.3</commons-beanutils.version>
    <commons-collections.version>3.2.2</commons-collections.version>
    <commons-codec.version>1.10</commons-codec.version>
    ...
```

For Hibernate, you can use something like this to override its version:

```
<properties>
    <hibernate.version>3.3.2.GA</hibernate.version>
    <hibernate-validator.version>3.1.0.GA</hibernate-validator.version>
</properties>
```

Comment: What didn't work? Did it fail to override the Hibernate version? What does ` mvn dependency:tree` print?